# Node: How to stream STDERR content from child_process.spawn()?

Tags: node.js, child-process, stderr, stdio, spawn

I'm using Node's child_process.spawn() to run shell commands, with the following code:

```
const process = require('child_process').spawn('whoami');

// this works...
process.stdout.on('data', function(buf) {
    console.log('HERE IS SOME STDOUT CONTENT "%s"', String(buf));
});

// this never works...
process.stderr.on('data', function(buf) {
    console.log('HERE IS SOME STDERR CONTENT "%s"', String(buf));
});

// this works, but doesn't let me stream STDERR content...
process.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('there was an error: ' + err);
});
```

Running the above valid command `whoami` lets me read the STDOUT data inside the function passed to `process.stdout.on`.

If I change my command to something invalid (that produces some STDERR content) like...

```
const process = require('child_process').spawn('whoami BADARGUMENTTOBREAKTHINGS');
```

...the `whoami` command outputs an error message to STDERR (in a normal shell), but in Node my function inside `process.stderr.on` is never executed.  I never see the `HERE IS SOME STDERR CONTENT` message.

I've also tried some other invalid shell commands like `cd folderthatdoesntexist` and `ls filenamethatdoesntexist` that should all produce STDERR content.

Answer (score 1):

After typing my question out, I figured out that it was as simple as the fact that you can't have spaces in the 1st argument to .spawn() ... you have to pass the rest of the command in as the 2nd argument with an array, i.e.

```
const process = require('child_process').spawn('whoami', ['BADARGUMENTTOBREAKTHINGS']);
```

This was unexpected because both .exec() and .spawnSync() work with spaces in the 1st argument.

Hopefully this can help someone else having the same issue in the future.